# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _store.configureStore) is not a function

Tags: javascript, redux, es6-modules

store.js

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

const logger = createLogger();

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(logger)(createStore);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  return createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, initialState);
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TrackList from './components/TrackList';
import {configureStore} from './store';
import * as actions from './actions';

const tracks = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Title 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Title 2'
  }
];

const store = configureStore();
store.dispatch(actions.setTracks(tracks));

ReactDOM.render(
  <TrackList />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Folder src consist index.js and store.js

Show message Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _store.configureStore) is not a function when F12

Help me thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edited on March 11th 2019:

This answer will likely no longer work. Please see discussion in comments below as to why, and what should be the actual solution.

---

You export a single function from your module, so your import should be:

```
import configureStore from './store';
```

You would use

```
import {configureStore} from './store';
```

if your export looked like

```
export default {
  configureStore: function(initialState) {
    return createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, initialState);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i'm newbie redux, thanks again

Comment: That `export default {...` in the end doesn't actually work anymore. You have to export by name now, in accordance with the specs. The export should be `export function configureStore (initialState) {...}`.

Comment: @HieuBui Note that this is an a ES6 issue that really has nothing to do with Redux.

Comment: Getting an error when only one export exists so named export doesn't work as per @DDS 's suggestion.

Comment: You can have a single named export. There being one export doesn't mean it is the default export.

Comment: This answer is old. It involves using a hack that doesn't conform to the specification. It also should no longer work in most environments. Read anywhere about ES6 imports for more info on how it should be done. The reason this worked at all is because implementations were not always spec compliant.